# Laravel: Add pagination to query

Tags: laravel

How can I add paginate to this query? The pagination data is not showing in my json response.

```
  $posts = Post::with('comments','settings')
    ->whereIn('user_id', function($query)
        use($id){
            $query->select('followable_id')
            ->from('followables')
            ->where('user_id', $id)->paginate(10);
        }
    )->orWhere('user_id', $id)
        ->latest()
        ->get();

    return response()->json($posts);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`->paginate(10);`

The paginate should be on the outside of the query (not within the `whereIn` closure)

Try to swap `->get();` with `->paginate(10);`

Answer (score 1):

A quick check of [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/pagination) shows:

> You may call paginate after setting other constraints on the query, such as where clauses:

Note it says **after** other constraints - it doesn't make sense to use pagination inside a `whereIn()` clause.  So in your case, that would be something like:

```
$posts = Post::with('comments','settings')
    // ... your code, no pagination ...
    )->orWhere('user_id', $id)
        ->latest()
        ->paginate(10);
```